# the output should display a hyphen (-) after the first 3 digits and subsequently a hyphen after every 4 digits

Tags: java

I have an assignment but i couldn't complete this question.
Previously I add inserted else if (counter == 7) { break; } after the counter==3 but I had removed since the question said to process as many digits as the user wants.

I do not know how to add to count every 4 digit for dash after the first 3 digits dash.

the code below is what I have.

please help and explain to me if possible. thanks :)

import java.util.Scanner;

public class question1 {

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    boolean notletter = false;
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    String phoneletter = "";
    int counter = 0;

    System.out.print("Enter a phone number in letters only: ");
    String phoneNumber = console.nextLine();

    String phnum2 = phoneNumber.replaceAll(" ", "");

    for (int i = 0; i <= phnum2.length() - 1; i++) {

        if (!(Character.isLetter(phnum2.charAt(i)))) {
            notletter = true;

            break;
        }
        {

            switch (Character.toUpperCase(phnum2.charAt(i))) {
                case 'A':
                case 'B':
                case 'C':
                    phoneletter = phoneletter + "2";
                    break;
                case 'D':
                case 'E':
                case 'F':
                    phoneletter = phoneletter + "3";
                    break;
                case 'G':
                case 'H':
                case 'I':
                    phoneletter = phoneletter + "4";
                    break;
                case 'J':
                case 'K':
                case 'L':
                    phoneletter = phoneletter + "5";
                    break;
                case 'M':
                case 'N':
                case 'O':
                    phoneletter = phoneletter + "6";
                    break;
                case 'P':
                case 'Q':
                case 'R':
                case 'S':
                    phoneletter = phoneletter + "7";
                    break;
                case 'T':
                case 'U':
                case 'V':
                    phoneletter = phoneletter + "8";
                    break;
                case 'W':
                case 'X':
                case 'Y':
                case 'Z':
                    phoneletter = phoneletter + "9";
                    break;

            }
            counter++;

            if (counter ==3) {

                phoneletter = phoneletter + "-";


                }


            }


        }



    if (notletter == true) {
        System.out.println("Please indicate only alphabets");
    } else {
        System.out.println(phoneletter);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You're doing too much in a single method. Create one method to read the input. Create one method to validate the input. Create one method to transform a letter into a digit. Then, in your main method, call the first two methods, write a loop calling the third one for each letter, and insert dashes when necessary.

Comment: Give a sample input and an expected output for that input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by editing the if-statement at the end of your code:

```
if (counter ==3) {

    phoneletter = phoneletter + "-";


}
```

Here you already checked if the counter is three. If it is, add a hyphen. The next thing to do is to check the case of "a hyphen after every 4 digits". To do this, we can check if `counter - 3` is a multiple of 4:

```
(counter - 3) % 4 == 0
```

However, this would make it insert an extra `-` at the end of the output if (input length - 1) is a multiple of 4. So we *shouldn't* add a hyphen if we reached the end of the string. This can be done by checking whether `i` is `phnom.length() - 1`:

```
i != phnom.length() - 1
```

If we combine all these conditions together, we get

```
if (counter == 3 || ((counter - 3) % 4 == 0 && i != phnom.length() - 1)) {
```

Note: This can actually be done using a regular expression, but since this is homework, I doubt this approach will be accepted. Here is how you do this with regex:

```
// phoneLetter is a string of digits without any hyphens
String result = phoneLetter.replaceAll("^\\d{3}|\\d{4}(?!$)", "$0-");
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your help. it works now. but however, phnom.length()-1 does it means minus 1? or adding a dash at every remaining 4 digits? also ((counter-3)%4==0 does it mean that after the 3 digits, remaining every 4 digits will indicate a dash? the same meaning as phnom.length()-1?

Comment: @JaniceTeng it means minus one. The line that adds the hyphen is `phoneletter = phoneletter + "-";`. Here I'm just checking whether a hyphen should be added. It should not be added if we reached the end of the string.

Comment: oh... so ((counter-3)%4==0 it means add a dash at the remaining every 4 digits after first 3 digits right? thank u for ur explanation as i am very very weak in java. thanks